# how to do groupon like animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am impressed by groupon animation at the beginning of the registration process, the guide for user to select the city and email address...

Is there any library to do that? I really like it.

Comment: Add an example or better explanation.

Comment: Why? Just go there and click once. It is simple jQuery CSS manipulation

Comment: Instead of telling us to go there, just provide a link

Comment: @Sean: Why is this not a question? I had not trouble answering it and neither did Zirak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Source code](http://assets1.grouponcdn.com/javascripts/app/subscriptions/multi_steps.js?t1cj1qyn)

All you'll ever need. Very simple. It just animates two divs to the left.

Now that I think about it, you can easily add this sort of animation yourself using just jQuery. For example, let's say you have two divs:

```
<div id='step1'>Lorem lipsum</div>
<div id='step2'>Lipsum lorem</div>
```

You can very simply add an animation:

```
$('#step1').animate({
    position : '-5px'
}, 1000);

$('#step2').animate({
    position: '100px'
}, 1000);
```

This is all off the top of my head, but I think you get the overall idea. For more info see the jQuery API for [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Answer (score 1):

It is a jquery plugin they wrote.

Look at the code here and view-source on the page to see the objects they manipulate
http://assets1.grouponcdn.com/javascripts/app/subscriptions/multi_steps.js?t1cj1qyn